# Is there a bash builtin for 'which'?

Tags: bash

I've been testing a minimal Fedora install. To check the path for interpreters like python or node, I normally use `which`.

I notice `which` isn't installed by default. I could add the package, but I wonder if there's a shell builtin that can be used to perform this common task.

I'm using bash 4.2.

Comment: Somehow a search for the Windows equivalent brought me here; for future viewers: "where" will tell you the given file's path.

Comment: I encourage anyone that comes across this Q to also read this U&L Q&A. It covers everything you ever wanted to know about `which`. [Why not use “which”? What to use then?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use `type`, which is a Bash builtin:

```
$ type -P which
which is /usr/bin/which
```

For documentation, see `help [t]ype`, which refers to the `type` section in the `bash` man page.

(`help type` prints the help pages for *two* [builtins which start with the string](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66067/how-to-match-name-exactly-with-bashs-help-builtin) "type", one of which is obsolete and completely unrelated to this.)

Comment: I like `type -a` myself. why the brackets in `[t]ype`?

Comment: `type -a` will print all things that the argument points to, and not just what would be executed when typing it.

Comment: I encourage anyone that comes across this Q to also read this U&L Q&A. It covers everything you ever wanted to know about `which`. [Why not use “which”? What to use then?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then)

Comment: The first thing in the list of `type -a` is always what it would execute. I do the same as Glenn and always use `type -a` too.

Comment: `type -p` doesn't show path if command is an alias. `type -P` always shows command path properly. i think. we should update accepted answer as `type -P` @l0b0

Answer (score 10):

You can use `type` or `command -v`. The output of `type` is human readable; the output of `command -v` can be executed by Bash.

Note that they are actually a little different. `type` and `command` look up the hashed value of the command. That is to say, if you type `cmd`, `type cmd` or `command -v cmd` will tell you exactly what will be run. They also work on aliases, Bash functions, and Bash builtins (although `type -p` will ignore these and only return true files).

`which` just does a search on the PATH. This is different because:

- If there is an alias, function, or builtin with the same name, it will be called instead.
- If a command was added earlier in the PATH since it was last hashed, it will be found by `which`, but executing that command will use the hashed value (you can force update the hash in Bash with `hash -r`).

Usually people really want `type`, not `which`, at least for interactive use, as they use it to find out "where is this command coming from when I run it?" You should only use `which` if you really want to do a PATH lookup.

Comment: `command -v` is the equivalent of `ksh` `whence`.

Comment: So we have `where`, `whence`, and of course also `who`, `why`, and `when`? Why is there no `what`?

Comment: `echo 'main(){printf("what\n");}' | sudo cc -x c - -o /usr/local/bin/what`